# Magento 2 - Error while creat account

Tags: magento2, error

I got this error when creating account:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getRedirectCookie() on null in Custom_Module/Controller/AccountCreatePost.php

What is possible causes for this error?

Comment: Have you solved your problem ? I also encountered with the same problem as yours.

Answer (score 0):

That error is due to override AccountCreatePost controller.

You have installed it in magento lower version 2.0.9 or lower and you are using method of magento 2.1.0 version or greater so that error throw

**getRedirectCookie()** this method is not available in magento lower version so remove that method or make it compatible to magento 2.0.x compitable

My suggestion use observer or plugin method instead of override controller.